# Javascript loop to hide all flash

Tags: javascript, flash

How can I make JavaScript loop left all `<object>` elements and hide them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
for (var i=0, n=objects.length;i<n;i++) objects[i].style.display='none';
```

---

Update. Playing with something I had thought about before. It works in Fx with object, but although I could make it work in IE with divs, I could not make it work in IE - not even with classnames on the object.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
object {
  display:block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// got some of this from http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml
function toggle() {
  var mysheet=document.styleSheets[0]
  var firstrule=mysheet.cssRules? mysheet.cssRules[0]: mysheet.rules[0]
  firstrule.style.display=(firstrule.style.display=="block")?"none":"block"
  return false
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="return toggle()">toggle the objects</a><br />
<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/tgbNymZ7vqY?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/tgbNymZ7vqY?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object>
<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VnT7pT6zCcA?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VnT7pT6zCcA?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object>
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/PhMCa1_9FYg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/PhMCa1_9FYg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you can do this with something like this css-rule:

```
html object { display: none; }
```

instead of javascript.

or use a class + javascript

```
 html object.no-show { display: none; }
```

and use a loop to apply the class on all objects.

or toggle the class to the body:

```
html body.hide-object object { display: none; }
```

this is with javascript with no loop.

Comment: But not on demand, right? Unless you loop and assign a className to each object, making it not interesting - as you just added to your answer ;)

Comment: That is correct. However I prefer toggling a class above toggling individual style properties by javascript.

Comment: I agree, my update to manipulate the CSS was just a combination of what you said and something I had wondered if it was possible. If you refer to the style.display, it is an exception to my rule ;)